# Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm trying to run the command ionic build android --release to build the apk but i am getting this error

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.623 secs Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: [Android SDK Platform 25]. Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw8IG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the SDK manager to install SDK Platform 25 manually. This should ask you to accept the license which should fix this error.

Comment: get me install SDK Platform 25 in CLI,  ??